# Python dice game gone wrong (single die vs. double dice)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I developed a simple Python dice game in which the user can play the game until they say 'no' to *'Lets play the Game : yes or no '*. There are also some inputs like how many dice you want to play (single die or double dice), how many sides you want in those dice. Also, if the user inputs how many dice >2 or <1 or sides >6 or <1 the program should throw a warning message.

Keeping this in my mind I wrote some code but the output has somehow gone wrong. When I switched to single dice the program stops automatically.

```
Welcome to the Dice Game for Single  Players
Lets play the Game : yes or no yes
Please Enter your Name: maddy
Hi maddy How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : 2
maddy , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : 6
Hey maddy your throw count is 1 and your dice pair is (2, 5) & total = 7
Lets play the Game : yes or no yes
Hi maddy How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : 2
maddy , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : 5
Hey maddy your throw count is 2 and your dice pair is (2, 5) & total = 7
Lets play the Game : yes or no yes
Hi maddy How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : 1
maddy , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : 5

Process finished with exit code 0
```

```
import random
print('Welcome to the Dice Game for Single  Players')
a=input('Lets play the Game : yes or no ')

if a== 'no':
    print('OOPS!! May be u can check other games u r interested in here')

elif a=='yes':
    b=str(input('Please Enter your Name: '))
    c=int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))

    while c<1 or c>2:
        print('Dice value should be 1 0r 2')
        c = int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))

d=int(input(f'{b} , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : '))


dice_count = 0
dice_total = 0
repeater=True

while a== 'yes' and c==1 and repeater:
    x=random.randint(1,d)
    dice_total = 0
    dice_count=dice_count+1
    dice_total=dice_total+x
    print(f'Hey {b} your throw count is {dice_count} and your dice number is {dice_total}')
    a = input('Lets play the Game : yes or no ')
    if a=='yes':
        c = int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))
        d = int(input(f'{b} , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : '))
        repeater=True

    elif a=='no':
        print('OOPS!! May be u can check other games u r interested in here')



while a == 'yes' and c == 2 and repeater:
    y=random.randint(1,d)
    z=random.randint(1,d)
    two=(y,z)
    dice_count = dice_count + 1
    dice_total=0
    dice_total = dice_total + sum(two)
    print(f'Hey {b} your throw count is {dice_count} and your dice pair is {two} & total = {dice_total}')
    a = input('Lets play the Game : yes or no ')
    if a == 'yes':
        c = int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))
        d = int(input(f'{b} , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : '))
        repeater = True

    elif a == 'no':
        print('OOPS!! May be u can check other games u r interested in here')
```

Comment: Your code has no path to return from the `c == 2` loop to the `c == 1` loop.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How do i correct it..Guide me

Comment: Matteo's answer is okay (though I'd still change a lot). A helper function should work just right for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say 2 for the first time, your program skip to the second while, so you can't reach the single dice mode. You should fix your code using methods like this:

DiceFunction:

```
def dice(dice_count, dice_total, c, d):
if c == 1:
    diceVal=random.randint(1,d)
else:
    y=random.randint(1,d)
    z=random.randint(1,d)
    diceVal = y + z
dice_count = dice_count + 1
dice_total=0
dice_total = dice_total + diceVal
print(f'Hey {b} your throw count is {dice_count} and your dice number is {dice_total}')
a = input('Lets play the Game : yes or no ')
if a=='yes':
    c = int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))
    d = int(input(f'{b} , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : '))
    return True
elif a=='no':
    print('OOPS!! May be u can check other games u r interested in here')
    return False
```

Main:

```
dice_count = 0
dice_total = 0 
repeater=True

print('Welcome to the Dice Game for Single  Players')
a=input('Lets play the Game : yes or no ')

if a== 'no':
    print('OOPS!! May be u can check other games u r interested in here')

elif a=='yes':
    b=str(input('Please Enter your Name: '))
    c=int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))

    while c<1 or c>2:
        print('Dice value should be 1 0r 2')
        c = int(input(f'Hi {b} How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2 : '))

d=int(input(f'{b} , How Many sides you want in a dice out of 1 to 6 : '))

while repeater:
    repeater = dice(dice_count, dice_total, c, d)
```

Comment: @patmcb Thanks bro for helping me out...It really works out but the dice count remains 1 for each game and (How Many Dice you want to play with?? 1 0r 2) if this value>2 or <1 program doesnt throws warning to the user and it simply jumps to the next question

Comment: Your welcome, i just moved your code into a function, try to improve it, you can do a function to ask the dice's number too